# Custom query or specific getter method for sonata_type_collection form type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have a Trip entity that has many HoneymoonComponent. In the TripAdmin, I am using a sonata_type_collection to edit inline all the HoneymoonComponent related:

```
$formMapper
        ->add('isHoneymoonEnabled', null)
        ->add('honeymoonComponents', 'sonata_type_collection', array('by_reference' => false), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',

    ));
```

This works properly, but what I would like to achieve, is to only show the honeymoonComponents that match a criteria (for example: HoneymoonComponent::enabled = false).

I can not find a way to specify a custom query for that, and I have a workaround which I don't know if it's good which is override the HoneymoonComponent::getHoneymoonComponent to only return the ones that match the criteria... but I don't much like it.

Is there a way to specify which "getter" method should sonata_type_collection to use? (or specify custom query). Both solutions would be fine for me.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I also tried in HoneymoonComponentAdmin:

    `public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);
        $rtAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
        $query
            ->andWhere("{$rtAlias}.enabled = true")
        ;
        return $query;
    }`

but only seems to take effect on the admin itself, not in embedded forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$formMapper
  ->add('isHoneymoonEnabled', null)
  ->add('honeymoonComponents', null, array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\MyEntity',
            'query_builder' => $this->modelManager->createQuery('My\Bundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'h')
                    ->where('h.enabled = 0'),
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
  ));
```

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work either (for type sonata_type_collection, which is what I want, a table to edit inline)

    `The options "class", "query_builder" do not exist.`

Comment: Please notice that instead of `sonata_type_collection` there is `null`

Comment: Yes, sorry I did, but this not allows me to create a new element inline.

Comment: This is not sonata_type_collection, see this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317211/add-a-query-filter-to-sonata-type-collection